# How to use PropTypes.checkPropTypes function to check the variable is array or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, typechecking, react-proptypes

I use the react PropTypes library like(I already applied babel):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

I have varabile like:

```
k=['something ok', 'something wrong'];
```

I know for most time the PropTypes.checkPropTypes function check the the dictionary structure. If the variable is not props but just normal variable defined in javascript.

Can you give me an example the PropTypes.checkPropTypes function check the array struction and give me the feedback of the result of check like the element of array is String and the length of the array.

ps: Actully, I want use different format to present different type of data.
if it is one length of array just present them, if it is more than one use different  to contain the string it have.